# DNSサーバーのIPアドレスについて

Tags: network, dns

ネットワーク周りについて色々と調べているうちに、IPアドレスの設定周りの仕組みについていくつか疑問が出てきました。

■疑問を持つに至った経緯
①PS4がWiMAXに繋がらない(接続はできるけれどDNSサーバーエラーで繋がらない)ため、以下のサイトを参考に設定しました。
https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14200321324

②無事に繋がったものの、「何故末尾に1を追加したものがセカンダリDNSになるのか」という疑問がわき、DNSサーバーについて調べ始めました。
GoogleのパブリックDNSなど色々なものがあり、自分で使うDNSサーバーを変えられることを知りました。(ちゃんと理解しているか怪しいですが…)
しかしここで、①で確認したDNSサーバーがプライベートIP(ゲートウェイと同じ番号でした)だったことを思い出し、「ローカルIPのDNSサーバーとは…？」と余計に分からなくなってしまいました。

③使っているモバイルルーターの管理画面に入って、そこで見れるDNSサーバーが①で設定したものと同じかを確認しようと思い付きました。
しかし、プライマリDNSもセカンダリDNSも全く違う番号でした。(プライベートIPではなかったです)

■本題
スマートフォン上で見たIPアドレスと、ルーターの管理画面で見たIPアドレスが違う理由が気になっています。

【1】前提として、モバイルルータは③で確認したDNSサーバーを用いて通信をしていると理解して良いでしょうか？

【2】【1】が正しいとして、①のスマートフォン上で確認したDNSのIPは何者ですか？ローカルネットワーク上ではそう見えているだけで、実際は③で確認したプライマリDNSを使っているのでしょうか？

【3】①で設定したセカンダリDNSのIPは何者ですか？(何故末尾に1を追加したものがセカンダリDNSになるのか)

以上、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: DNSサーバーは一枚岩ではありません。スタブリゾルバーをPS4、フルサービスリゾルバーをルータに置き換えてJPRSの説明を見てみてください。 https://jprs.jp/glossary/index.php?ID=0158

Comment: リンクありがとうございます。どうも色々と勘違いしているみたいですね…。もう少し調べてみます。

Answer (score 0):

おそらくあなたの見た「スマートフォンの」 IP アドレスは (スマホ本体および DNS の)  WiFi 側ではなくて 4G 側のアドレスなのでしょう。なのでモバイルルータの表示と異なっているのでしょう。

A1. Yes
A2. 上記
A3. その解説は大嘘っつか適当っす。

たいていのインターネット接続契約では ISP の DNS サーバを２つ（以上）提供してくれます。片方をプライマリ DNS サーバ、片方をセカンダリ DNS サーバと呼びます。そして、普通は DHCP でルーターのグローバル IP アドレスが提供される際に ISP の DNS サーバの IP アドレスも一緒に提供されます。

んで複数の ISP において、プライマリ DNS サーバの IP アドレスが `xxx.yyy.zzz.123` であるとき、セカンダリ DNS サーバの IP アドレスが `xxx.yyy.zzz.124` であることが多い（要するに `+1` ）ようです。なのでリンク先 Q&A では `+1` と言い切っちゃっています。でもそういう規則や慣例があるわけではないのでセカンダリ DNS サーバの IP アドレスが `+1` でないことはごく普通にあります。

セカンダリ DNS サーバの IP アドレスが `xxx.yyy.zzz.234` であった場合 `+1` 設定は間違いなのですが、ほとんどすべてのスマホ（や PC）ではプライマリ DNS サーバに障害があったときだけセカンダリ DNS サーバを使うので、プライマリ DNS サーバに問題が無いとき、スマホのセカンダリ DNS 設定が誤っていても使われないので何の問題も発生しないのです。

---

スマホをモバイルルータに接続して使う際の DNS 設定値のお勧め度

1. モバイルルータの LAN 側アドレス (モバイルルータは DNS 代理サーバになるはず)
2. ISP の提供してきた DNS サーバ (モバイルルータが使う DNS をスマホでも使う)
3. 信頼できる公開汎用 DNS (google public DNS `8.8.8.8` と `8.8.4.4` が有名)

手動設定するのは面倒でしょ？

Comment: PSの設定をした時点で、本当は管理画面に書いてあるDNSのIPアドレスを入れるべきだったということでしょうか？スマートフォンで確認したものを入れても普通に繋がっていますが…

Comment: オイラの 2.ISP の DNS キャッシュサーバを使うを採用したいのであれば Yes 管理画面の DNS は ISP の DNS のはずなので。でもオイラなら手動設定を避けて 1. にするか、手動設定するなら 3. を選び 2. は採用しないでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

> 【1】前提として、モバイルルータは③で確認したDNSサーバーを用いて通信をしていると理解して良いでしょうか？

良いと思います。

> 【2】【1】が正しいとして、①のスマートフォン上で確認したDNSのIPは何者ですか？ローカルネットワーク上ではそう見えているだけで、実際は③で確認したプライマリDNSを使っているのでしょうか？

モバイルルーターのLAN側のIPだと思います。

ルーターは接続している LANと、WANとで、それぞれのネットワークのIPアドレスを持っています。

```
internet
   |                /// WAN側のIPで通信を行う
モバイルルーター
   |                /// LAN側のIPで通信を行う
 スマホ
```

また、モバイルルーターは、自身が管理する無線LAN向けに DNSサービスを提供しています。スマートフォンからのDNS問い合わせは、ルーターがいったん受け取ります。ルーターは、WAN（ISPやInternet）側のDNSに再問合せを行い、その結果を スマートフォンに返します。

```
WAN上のDNS ←→ モバイルルーターのDNS ←→ スマートフォンやPS4
```

> 【3】①で設定したセカンダリDNSのIPは何者ですか？(何故末尾に1を追加したものがセカンダリDNSになるのか)

適当に入れただけで実在しない可能性が高いです。
セカンダリDNSは設定しなくても大丈夫だと思います。